# Determine last day of given month

Tags: macros, datetime

I want to determine how many days there are in a particular month.

Using the `datenumber` package, I thought I could simply set the date to the 1st of the *next* month and then back up one day would be the end of the month and extract the date. Well that sure *seemed* simple when I came up with it, but then got stuck at actually extracting the day of the month.

So, what do I need to replace

```
\xdef\LastDayOfMonth{\value{dateday}}
```

with the get the number of days in the month.

### Notes:

- I am not opposed to additional packages, so any package solution is fine.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datenumber}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{GivenDateCounter}
\newcommand{\LastDayOfMonth}{XX}%
\newcommand{\NumberOfDaysInMonth}[2]{%
    % #1 = YYYY
    % #2 = MM
    \ifnum#2<12\relax
        % Since this is NOT Dec we can just go to the 1st of the next
        % month and back up one day.
        \setmydatenumber{GivenDateCounter}%
                {#1}%
                {\numexpr#2+1\relax}% Next month
                {01}% First of the month
    \else
        % Since this IS Dec we can just go to Jan 1st of the next
        % year and back up one day.
        \setmydatenumber{GivenDateCounter}%
                {\numexpr#1+1\relax}% Next Year
                {01}% Next day is Jan next year since current month is 12
                {01}% First of the month
    \fi
    \addtocounter{GivenDateCounter}{-1}% Now we are the end of the required month
    \xdef\LastDayOfMonth{\value{dateday}}%  <---- Stuck here.
    \typeout{**** \string\LastDayOfMonth for #1-#2=\LastDayOfMonth}%
}%

\begin{document}

\foreach \YearNumber in {2013, 2014} {%
    \foreach \MonthNumber in {01, 02, ..., 12} {%
        \par
        Number of Days in \YearNumber-\MonthNumber{} is 
        \NumberOfDaysInMonth{\YearNumber}{\MonthNumber}.%
    }%
}%


\end{document}
```

Comment: The number of days in each month is independent of the year except for February which depends on the year being a leap year or not. Wouldn't it be easier to just encode the leap year algorithm and use an if-cascade? 

`if year is not divisible by 4 then common year
else if year is not divisible by 100 then leap year
else if year is divisible by 400 then leap year
else common year`

Comment: @ChristianLindig: Good suggestion, but I'd prefer not to code it if possible.  Although the two solutions below that compute it makes it look a lot simpler than I had thought it would be.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd say to use `\arabic{dateday}`, since `\value{dateday}` is not expandable (it expands to the registers name, not to the value). However it doesn't work, because `dateday` is not set.

Since you're not bound to `datetime`, here's a version with `xparse`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,pgffor,multicol}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand\NumberOfDaysInMonth { m m }
 {
  \grill_numb_days_month:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Npn \grill_numb_days_month:nn #1 #2
 {
  \int_case:nn { #2 }
   {
    {1}{31}
    {2}{ \grill_if_leap_year:nTF { #1 } { 29 } { 28 } }
    {3}{31}
    {4}{30}
    {5}{31}
    {6}{30}
    {7}{31}
    {8}{31}
    {9}{30}
    {10}{31}
    {11}{30}
    {12}{31}
   }
 }

\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \grill_if_leap_year:n #1 { p,T,F,TF }
 {
  \bool_if:nTF
   {
    \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } != 0 }
    ||
    (
     \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 4 } == 0 }
     &&
     \int_compare_p:n { \int_mod:nn { \int_div_truncate:nn { #1 } { 100 } } { 4 } != 0 }
    ) 
   }
   { \prg_return_false: }
   { \prg_return_true: }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\foreach \YearNumber in {1900, 2000, 2012, 2013} {%
    \foreach \MonthNumber in {1, 2, ..., 12} {%
        \par
        Number of Days in \YearNumber-\MonthNumber{} is 
        \NumberOfDaysInMonth{\YearNumber}{\MonthNumber}.%
    }
}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\NumberOfDaysInMonth` is fully expandable, so

```
\edef\MDCCFebruary{\NumberOfDaysInMonth{1700}{2}}
```

would define the macro to expand to `28`.

[image]

The conditional command `\grill_if_leap_year:nTF` can also be used in other situations. It has the four forms: predicate, true, false and true/false.

Answer (score 9):

You can use package `pgfcalendar` from the `pgf` bundle. The utility macros accept date input as `<year>-<month>-last` for the last day in `<month>` of `<year>`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}

\begin{document} 

\newcount\datecount
\newcommand\daysinmonth[2]{%
  \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#1-#2-last}{\datecount}%
  \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\the\datecount}{\dyear}{\dmonth}{\dday}%
  \dday
}%

\daysinmonth{2012}{2}\par
\daysinmonth{2014}{2}\par
\daysinmonth{2014}{5}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

An old-school way using `\ifnum` and mod calculations from [`intcalc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/intcalc):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol,pgffor,intcalc}
\newcommand{\NumberOfDaysInMonth}[2]{% \NumberOfDaysInMonth{<year>}{<month>}
  \ifcase#2
  \or 31% January
  \or% February
    \ifnum\intcalcMod{#1}{4}=0
      \ifnum\intcalcMod{#1}{100}=0
        \ifnum\intcalcMod{#1}{400}=0
          29% Year divisible by 4 and 100 and 400
        \else
          28% Year divisible by 4 and 100 (not 400)
        \fi
      \else
        29% Year divisible by 4 (not 100 nor 400)
      \fi
    \else
      28% Year not divisible by 4
    \fi
  \or 31% March
  \or 30% April
  \or 31% May
  \or 30% June
  \or 31% July
  \or 31% August
  \or 30% September
  \or 31% October
  \or 30% November
  \or 31% December
  \else
    999% Invalid month...
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}

\foreach \YearNumber in {1900, 2000, 2012, 2013} {%
    \foreach \MonthNumber in {1, 2, ..., 12} {%
        \par
        Number of Days in \YearNumber-\MonthNumber{} is 
        \NumberOfDaysInMonth{\YearNumber}{\MonthNumber}.%
    }
}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```